# Serving Bootstrap Docs locally, ?alternative to Jekyll

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll, mamp

This is probably a dumb question, but I was wondering if there is a way to serve or create the Bootstrap docs locally using something other than jekyll?  I guess the recommended way is to navigate to your bootstrap source directory and serve the pages with jekyll.  It does however look like the compiled pages are at _gh_pages, and you could serve those with a local web server like MAMP ?

Comment: Wow! This is a huge mess! haha. Don't panic though! I'll add an answer. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bootstrap can be downloaded from here](http://getbootstrap.com/) and can be used in any website.

[Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) is a static website generator that can use Bootstrap or not as a layout framework. It's up to you using it or not.

A local server as [Mamp](https://www.mamp.info/en/) or [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) are useful usually when you have some server-side code, as `php` and `sql`. Also, some requests like [Facebook like/share buttons](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) are only visible on local browsers when you are serving the site locally via `localhost`.

Bottom line:

- You can have Jekyll - and run jekyll via `jekyll serve` at `localhost:4000`;
- You can add Bootstrap to any project;
- You don't need Mamp or other local server to view locally any of these previous things. You'll definitely will need it to view `.php` pages and so on.

Hope to have helped to clear these subjects to you!

:)

Comment: Actually, after compiling bootstrap there is a _gh_pages directory which can be used as the document root for a local web server like MAMP.